# Impact of idle connections on max_connections in postgres

Tags: python, postgresql, fastapi

I've been getting `'M': 'sorry, too many clients already'` lately when my FastAPI endpoint is called, throwing 500.

I tried running this script:

```
select pid as process_id, 
       usename as username, 
       datname as database_name, 
       client_addr as client_address, 
       application_name,
       backend_start,
       state,
       state_change
from pg_stat_activity;
```

And I could see ~50 connections with state `idle` (which I believe means connections that are established but not making any transactions).

My postgres has a limit of 100 `max_connections` (in .conf).

Other than eating RAM, is there any impact of these "idle" connections on `max_connections` or postgres in general?

Is there something my FastAPI app is doing wrong:

`utils.py`

```py
def get_db_instance():
    try:
        db = SessionLocal()
        yield db
    finally:
        db.close()
```

`crud.py`

```py
from utils import get_db_instance
def add(obj, db: Session):
   db.add(obj)
   db.commit()
```

Answer (score 0):

There are several problems with having many idle connections:

- the “snapshot” that each statement has to take (to determine which data it can see and which not) becomes slower
- many idle connections mean many connections that could become active at the same time, thus overloading the database (bad for performance)
- the more connections you have, the less resources (`work_mem`) you can give each of them

Therefore, the best solution is to use a moderately sized connection pool.

If you are dealing with a connection leak in your application, that's a problem you will have to fix on the application side.